# PHP Memcache user created objects

Tags: php, memcached, user-object

Need some help about with Memcache.

I have created a class and want to store its objects in Memcache, finding trouble doing so please tell me where am I going wrong. Following is my code

```
// Class defined by me
    class User
    {
    public $fname;
    public $age;        
        /**
         * @return unknown
         */
        public function getfname() {
            return $this->fname;
        }

        /**
         * @return unknown
         */
        public function getage() {
            return $this->age;
        }

/**
         * @return unknown
         */
        public function setfname() {
            return $this->fname;
        }

        /**
         * @return unknown
         */
        public function setage() {
            return $this->age;
        }
    }

//Code for Storing
<?php
$objMemcache = new Memcache();
        $objMemcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);


$obj = new User();
$obj->setfname('John');
$obj->setage(32);

$objMemcache->set('user1', $obj, false, 60);


$obj1 = new User();
$obj1->setfname('Doe');
$obj1->setage(23);

$objMemcache->set('user2', $obj1, false, 60);

var_dump($objMemcache->get('user1'));

?>
```

The problem is I am not able to make sure if the object is actually getting store in Memache coz when i try to retrieve it using the $objMemcache->get($key), the var_dump function prints nothing.

Please help.

---

Can you please explain the error in my code.

Thanks soulmerge, Frank and Kevin, the solution worked, just another doubt.

Making the class variables private worked fine but when i try to convert the class object into a JSON_STRING using json_encode() it gives me again an empty value, any suggestions on that

Comment: The third parameter to $objMemcache->set() should be an integer (0 in your case)

Comment: I dropped your code in a file, removed the <?php tag in the middle, and executed it.  var_dump returned a User object, as expected.  The values of fname and age are null, due to the error Kevin points out below, but the memcache calls are working fine.  If they weren't, I believe get() would have returned null or false instead of an empty object.

Have you verified that memcached is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is wrong, try this :

```
<?php

// use this to display errors
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',true);

// Class defined by me
class User
{
    private $fname;
    private $age;        
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getfname() {
            return $this->fname;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getage() {
            return $this->age;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function setfname($value) {
            $this->fname = $value;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function setage($value) {
            $this->age = $value;
    }
}

$objMemcache = new Memcache();
$objMemcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);

$obj = new User();
$obj->setfname('John');
$obj->setage(32);
$objMemcache->set('user1', $obj, false, 60);

$obj1 = new User();
$obj1->setfname('Doe');
$obj1->setage(23);
$objMemcache->set('user2', $obj1, false, 60);

var_dump($objMemcache->get('user1'));
```